# Can the Android "Always-on" VPN setting be relied upon to route all traffic through VPN?

Tags: privacy, android, vpn, google-apps

If a user sets up a stock Android device to use a VPN and uses the "**Always-on**" [setting](https://support.google.com/android/answer/9089766?hl=en), can they be sure[1] that no traffic will leak outside of the VPN?

[1] Assuming no malware is installed by the user and the OS is not trying to deliberately circumvent the VPN secretly.

Comment: Are you considering VPN apps, or only the built-in VPN client? For the former, there is also a "Block connections without VPN" sub-option if "Always-on VPN" is enabled (the built-in client seems to only have the latter, but it's implemented differently so maybe the former is implied).

Comment: I'm open to all options, but I am just looking for one that reliably prevents any non-VPN traffic leaks without rooting the device.  I recall reading somewhere that traffic can leak during boot process, etc before VPN service is functional or if the process dies, etc.  I assumed someone here would know more about the potential pitfalls.